# Is using bootstrap or a theme cheating?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently new to HTML and CSS. I completed codecademy's HTMl/CSS course yesterday and started working on something which doesnt really have a use but it will touch on everything and I will finish it as I learn more including PHP. I am using bootstrap right now and it honestly feels like I am cheating. I have tried to do everything myself but it basically gives you a navbar which I wont just steal and use, I will try to make my own later on. This is my current site: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BUtZ.png

What should I be using? Should I cut out bootstrap and try to do everything with my own CSS?
I mean I did use my own CSS for the positioning but it doesnt seem like much. What do professionals use? Thanks.

Comment: Is using an electric screwdriver instead of a manual one cheating?  You shouldn't use an electric screwdriver in every situation, but when you're in a situation that calls for it why wouldn't you use it?

Comment: Generally writing everything from scratch yourself is considered a bad thing unless you have some real reason to do so (unless its for fun or educational purposes).

Comment: Hmm, yeah I see what both of you mean. I just cant get over the fact of how simple HTML and CSS really is with bootstrap. I guess ill have to wait until I get into PHP for more of a challenge.

Comment: No matter if it is css, html, js or any other language. You should be able to understand the concepts of a foreign library/framework before you use it, so that you know where the pitfalls, limitations and bottlenecks are. Therefore you need to have a good understanding of the language itself. With frameworks you can focus on the really important parts of your project, they give you a foundation of code that solves problems developers already had, but they also hiding many things from you, so they don't release you from understanding the concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Professionals mainly use Bootstrap or Foundation (since these are the most popular frameworks). If you're completely new, it's probably not a bad idea to code some websites from scratch to improve and probably even perfect your basic HTML/CSS skills and once you're comfortable I highly recommend using a framework. As for Bootstrap you can [check out the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/). It is very detailed and once you've figured out the basics, you're way faster than coding everything from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking a professional application parts from a CSS framework of choise and goes arround to customizing it as needed for the application. Of course in order to learn you should neglect those when just starting in order to learn more.

professionaly speaking you use as much "premade" code as possible. That is the reason for the grat ammount of frameworks in any language.

is like asking is it okay to use JQuery it feels like cheating normally I would write like 20 lines of code but using JQuery it became a one liner.